# C# Stream text/data to zip/gpg instead of passing app a filename?

Tags: c#, zip, stream, pipe, gnupg

I currently have an app written in C# that can take a file and encrypt 
it using gpg.exe

What I'm trying to do is, instead of 
1. Creating a file (from database queries usually) 
2. encrypting the file 
3. deleting the non-encrypted file

I want to

1. Gather info into memory (into a dictionary or a list or whatever)
2. stream the text/data into gpg.exe to end up with the encrypted file 
   outputted

I've looked into pipestream, redirecting standard input to the gpg 
process,  etc, but I haven't figured out a way to trick  gpg.exe into 
accepting streamed text/data instead of a file on the hard drive.

Initially figured if I could do it for gpg, I could also do it for Zip 
as well, but I'm wondering if it's even possible. 
Found some refs to popen which seems to be php related, but nothing 
for c#.

Essentially, I'm looking to do the below programatically with text.txt 
being stuff in memory streamed to the app instead of an actual file on 
the hard drive.

C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG>type C:\test.txt | zip > plubber.zip 
C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG>type C:\test.txt | gpg -er 
"mycomp_operations " > Test.pgp

Thanks for any help you may be able to give :)

Tony!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DotNetZip to create a zip file in-memory, but I don't know how that would interface with the gpg stuff.   DotNetZip can do AES encryption, but that is obviously a different model from PGP or GPG.

Just a quick googly search turned up
[this hint](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/gnupgdotnet.aspx) on GPG.

Looks like they run the gpg.exe in a separate process, sitting there waiting for input.

Comment: I've looked at that and have tried incorporating some of their code into an app for this, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the BouncyCastle C# implementation at:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

This will allow GPG inprocess encryption and decryption without external files.  I am currently using it to do the same thing for a BizTalk pipeline component.

Answer (score 1):

Benton Stark has written a good wrapper for GnuPG which demonstrates (among other things) how to take data from a Stream, pipe it into the GPG executable and write the output back to a stream - all in C#.

Benton has answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214026/gnupg-wrapper-with-c-sharp) with a link to his website. Benton writes:

> You can try using my open source and free GnuPG wrapper for C# (and
>   VB.NET). All the code is licensed via MIT, non-GPL restrictions. You
>   can find the release with source code on Sourceforge.net.
>
> http://sourceforge.net/projects/starksoftopenpg/

Answer (score 0):

Well, named-pipes does most of what you are discussing, but to be honest it isn't worth it... in most cases, a temp file is a reasonable approach.

Comment: I agree, but was asked to look into doing this w/o having an unencrypted file on a drive at any point in the operation. It's PCI related. It's overkill, but I suppose it'll make folk ooh and ahh over our security.

Answer (score 0):

Using our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) components you can avoid calling external program for ZIP or PGP operations. The components operate with streams and don't need temporary files.