# PGP decrypt file via ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, pgp, gnupg

I'm using the technique described on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22055/Automated-File-Decryption-Using-GnuPG-and-C) page to decrypt a file PGP.

But once in a while you will see a popup to put the passphrase in command despite having indicated their passphrase to
decrypt the file.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1214026/34397

Comment: Thanks for the comment but in your solution happens the same thing I've described.

Comment: Maybe it's the wrong password?

Answer (score 1):

When invoking gpg, try to make the call with these arguments:

```
> gpg --batch --yes --passphrase <the passphrase> --output <output file> --decrypt <encrypted file>
```